# Downloading all dependencies for a Perl module

Tags: perl, dependencies

This may be a duplicate question, so pardon my search skills.

I need to download all dependencies for a specific Perl module (local::lib and others) on a Windows/cygwin machine (with Perl 5.10.1) and move them to a Solaris machine (with Perl 5.8.8) that has no Internet connection.

I have seen minicpan suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873329/how-do-i-install-perl-modules-on-machines-without-an-internet-connection), but creating a complete replica of a CPAN is not an option as I'm on a corporate network with limited bandwidth. CPAN::Mini has some filtering options, but it deals with paths instead of dependencies.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the `cpan2dist` utility contained in the Perl distribution. (It's in `/usr/bin` in my Cygwin installation.)

> ```
> cpan2dist --help
> ```
>
> Will create a distribution of type FMT of the modules
>      specified on the command line, and all their prerequisites.
>
> Can also create a distribution of type FMT from a local
>      archive and all it's prerequisites

Haven't tried it, but it sounds like what you're after.

Comment: I was expecting the typical "perl -MCPAN -e 'install module'" response and was pleasantly surprised!  Will have to try this out sometime.

Comment: Thanks! I'm accepting this answer, but haven't tried it myself (just used a different machine with Internet access :-P). But from what I've seen in cpan2dist options, you still have to compile all packages and dependencies. I used the following command: `cpan2dist --format CPANPLUS::Dist::Build --buildprereq --skiptest --keepsource local::lib` and it gave me errors compiling prerequisites, so I didn't look further into it. If someone has a cleaner way of just downloading the sources, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

cpanminus has an option to do exactly that: --scandeps and --save-dists. Read more about that option on a blog post explaining [the new features of cpanm 1.4](http://bulknews.typepad.com/blog/2011/03/cpanm-14-is-out-the-greatest-release-ever.html).

Comment: Thanks, this does look good. But I still have the issue that I had before with differing Perl versions. Running `cpanm --scandeps --save-dists -L /tmp/perl5 local::lib` with Perl 5.12.3 yields local::lib only as all other dependencies are in core already. But I'd need a way to specify for which Perl version I want to test against; kind of like an automated tool to download the output of http://deps.cpantesters.org/. Which might not be such a bad idea after all...

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303468/4940240 has a nice thought: use "-L /dev/null" so that cpanm assumes, that no module ist installed. it will download all non-core modules (as I understand it)