# How to install perl modules with all dependencies in a RHEL machine without internet

Tags: perl

I would like to know is there any way to install perl modules with all its dependencies in a Redhat Linux machine without internet connection(for some security reasons the machine is not connected to internet)...I can download the modules from some other machine which have internet and then transfer the files using shared drive. But the challenge is to download all the dependencies of the package....Is there any other tool like cpan to download the packages with its dependencies. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [How do I install Perl modules on machines without an Internet connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1873329/176646)

Comment: you can mirror cpan to a drive, then mount the drive.