# How to install Net::SFTP perl module in Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: linux, perl

I am looking to implement an SFTP module for my Linux log archival and need some help to install the
[`Net::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP)
module.

I am using a RHEL7 system which does not have internet access or an active yum repository and also do not have
[`CPAN`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN)
installed.

I tried to build the module but got the below error

> Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.87]$ perl Makefile.PL
>   Can't locate ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Makefile.PL line 4.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 4.

Comment: [Net::SFTP](http://p3rl.org/Net::SFTP) or [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://p3rl.org/Net::SFTP::Foreign)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873329/how-do-i-install-perl-modules-on-machines-without-an-internet-connection

Comment: NET::SFTP @choroba

Comment: @AJ_NOVICE: Please use capital letters correctly. In this case it's clear that you mean `Net::SFTP`, but often it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the
[`CPAN::Mini`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini)
module. It allows you to download a snapshot of the CPAN repository which you can copy to your isolated system and use to build modules as normal